# manually read a file in the files directory

Tags: android

Friends, My application has to get current gps position in every seconds and write this data as byte array to a file in files directory. To check the data in that file I tried to open mnually. But i couldn't open. How can i read the file. The file is a text file

Comment: you should accept some answers from your other questions

Comment: @Aaron Saunders, I accepetd all answers.

Comment: What do you mean by 'cannot read'? Any error log?

Answer (score 0):

```
private static String readFileAsString(String file) throws IOException {
    byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) new File(file).length()];
    BufferedInputStream stream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
    stream.read(bytes);
    return new String(bytes);
}
```

Comment: I mean, i can't open the file from the DDMS/fileExplorer/data/data/myPackage/files manually, not by code. One more doubt, i can see above folder for my emulator only. for my real device i cant see the that folders. is there any setting to be changed to get that folders for my real device??